# How can I show contextual ads after a user filtered page contents by keyword?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I am building a social bookmarking service that is monetized in part by Google Adsense. However, I don't know how to influence how the ads are displayed. I think Google scans my pages and decides itself which ads to show where. Navigation on my site is mainly based on the selection of categories or tags being provided by the users. So after a user filters a list of bookmarks by the tag "SEO", I think I know pretty well what he is looking for. So I am looking for a service that allows me to show contextual ads for these particular keywords.

How I can guide Google to show relevant ads?

Can you recommend an alternative ad network, that gives me more control?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Let Google do it's thing. You can help of course. Create a sitemap for every possible page on your site, This includes the use of parameters if necessary. You can automate this and it should be extremely simple to do. From there Google can call up each page and determine what needs to happen.

What you are forgetting is that Google needs that information for bidding purposes as well. If you try and short circuit the process, your ad revenue will not be what you think.